# Motherboard replaced, drive letter screwed, not booting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, drive-letter

I have replaced the motherboard of my computer (with the same model), reattached every device, (I have 3 physical drives, with few logic drives inside).
Not my computer boots up, but when windows 7 starts, I get the choice to try to repair or boot. The second one fails with error 0x7B.
If I go with the recovery and I look at the log, or I open up the terminal, I see that all the drive letters are screwed up, for examples, it says that Windows is on "M:" (It was C:).
How do I change the drive letters for all the logic drives from the recovery?

EDIT:
I've unplugged any other drive, but now the assigned letter is "I".
If I run Diskpart with command "list Volume" this is the output:

```
volume 0  C  System reserved  NTFS 
volume 1  I  Win 7            NTFS
volume 2  D  Data partition   NTFS 
volume 3  E  Data partition   NTFS
volume 4  F  Swap             NTFS 
volume 5  G  Data partition   NTFS
volume 6  H  Data partition   NTFS
```

I have used Diskpart to reassign letters the right way, and I've done fixboot and fixmbr after replacing letters, but as soon as I reboot, everything goes back as listed by diskpart. I need also to leave the reserved system without letter, but it gets C assigned automatically :\
If instead of recovery, I try to boot, I get BSOD with error 0x0000007B

Comment: Unplug all the other drives from your motherboard and boot from the drive with windows installed. If your MBR is on another disk, this might be an issue, otherwise, let me know the results.

Comment: I would second what Jason said. Plug in only your boot drive and try to see if the boot succeeds. Do you have SATA or IDE drives?

Comment: I've added diskpart tests and volume table. I have sata drives, AHCI mode